# Nuxt2 cookie-universal server only

Tags: javascript, vue.js, cookies, vuejs2, nuxt.js

Is it possible to create a cookie in nuxt2 and keep it on server side only? So that I won't see it in the devtools/Application

Answer (score 0):

Cookies are meant to be sent back to the browser. If what you're looking for has to remain in the server only you could consider using a middleware that keeps that data in memory, filesystem or redis as example